# Как исправить формулу расчета очков за прогноз?

Tags: javascript

Имеется форма для ввода данных:

Прогноз - вводятся 2 цифры - предполагаемый счет матча (другими словами количество голов забитые командами).

Результат - вводятся 2 цифры - конечный результат матча.

```js
function ballResult() {
  var prog1 = document.getElementById('prog1').value,
    /* прогноз голов забитых командой 1*/
    prog2 = document.getElementById('prog2').value,
    /* прогноз голов забитых командой 2*/
    res1 = document.getElementById('res1').value,
    /* результат - забитые командой 1*/
    res2 = document.getElementById('res2').value,
    /* результат - забитые командой 2*/
    ball = 9 - Math.abs(prog1 - res1) - Math.abs(prog2 - res2); /* формула начисления очков */
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ball; /* вывод начисленнх очков */
}
```

```css
#prog1,
#prog2,
#res1,
#res2 {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> <b>Прогноз  </b> Питтсбург</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="prog1" value="" placeholder="голы команды 1">

        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="prog2" value="" placeholder="голы команды 2">

        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Нэшвилл</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td> <b>Результат  </b> Питтсбург</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="res1" value="" placeholder="голы команды 1">

        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="res2" value="" placeholder="голы команды 2">

        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Нэшвилл</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>

          <a href="#" onclick='ballResult()' class="submit">Рассчитать</a>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">

          Очки <output id="result"></output>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Формула начисления очков должна начислять очки исходя из установленных условий:

```
    за 1 матч можно получить максимум 9 очков, минимум - 0 очков.

    1. Если игрок угадал исход матча (выигрыш, ничья или поражение), то ему начисляются очки в диапазоне от 3 до 9. Чем точнее прогноз к результату матча, тем очков больше.
    2. Игрок получает 1 очко при не угаданном исходе, если он получил за матч 2,5 штрафных балла (ШБ - как они рассчитываются см.ниже под спойлером).
    3. В остальных случаях очки за матч не начисляются.

    При угаданном исходе игрок может получить 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, или 3 очка в зависимости от количества штрафных баллов (заданы диапазоном) в соответствии со следующей таблицей:

    -----------------
       Штраф    Очки
    -----------------
        0        9  (угадан счет)
     2 - 2,5     7
      4 - 6      6
    6.5 - 9      5
    9.5 - 12     4
       >12       3
    -----------------

    Вот примеры начисления очков с которыми можно сверятся:

    Прогноз   Результат   Очки
      3-2        3-2        9    (угадан счет матча)

      3-2        4-3        7    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 2)
      3-3        4-4        7    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 2)
      3-2        4-2        7    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 2,5)

      3-2        5-4        6    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 4)
      3-3        5-5        6    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 4)
      3-2        5-3        6    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 4,5)
      3-2        5-2        6    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 5)
      3-2        4-1        6    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 5)
      3-2        6-5        6    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 6)
      3-3        6-6        6    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 6)

      3-2        6-4        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 6,5)
      3-2        6-3        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 7)
      3-2        6-2        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 7,5)
      3-2        4-0        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 7,5)
      3-2        7-6        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 8)
      3-3        7-7        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 8)
      3-2        7-5        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 8,5)
      3-2        7-4        5    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 9)

      3-2        7-3        4    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 9,5)
      3-2        7-2        4    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 10)
      3-3        8-8        4    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 10)
      3-2        8-6        4    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 10,5)
      3-2        8-5        4    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 11)
      3-2        8-4        4    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 11,5)
      3-3        9-9        4    (угадан исход, количество ШБ = 12)

      3-2        8-2        3    (угадан исход, количество ШБ >12)
      3-3       10-10       3    (угадан исход, количество ШБ > 12)
      3-2       14-1        3    (угадан исход, количество ШБ > 12)

      3-2        3-3        1    (исход не угадан, количество ШБ = 2,5)
      4-4        3-4        1    (исход не угадан, количество ШБ = 2,5)

      2-0        1-2        0    (исход не угадан, количество ШБ > 2,5)
      3-3        4-2        0    (исход не угадан, количество ШБ > 2,5)

Формула, которая сейчас прописана в коде частично начисляет очки с ошибками. То есть угаданный счет и ошибку в 1 отклонение она считает правильно. Но остальное не правильно ( в частности не учитывает угаданный/не угаданный исход. 

В javascript знаком поверхностно.Надеюсь на вашу доброту.
```

Могу показать этот код написанный в Visual Basic.

```
Function calc01(score1 As String, score2 As String, Optional parm As Integer)
   Dim goal1 As Integer
   Dim goal2 As Integer
   Dim goal1p As Integer
   Dim goal2p As Integer
   Dim okm As Integer
   Dim orm As Integer
   Dim pos As Integer
   Dim shtraf As Single
   Dim f_ot As Boolean

   If Replace(score1, " ", "") = "" Or Replace(score2, " ", "") = "" Or score1 = "0" Or score2 = "0" Then
      calc01 = ""
      Exit Function
   End If

   score1 = Replace(score1, ":", "-")
   score1 = Replace(score1, "î", "o", , , vbTextCompare)
   score1 = Replace(score1, "á", "o", , , vbTextCompare)

   score2 = Replace(score2, ":", "-")
   score2 = Replace(score2, "î", "o", , , vbTextCompare)
   score2 = Replace(score2, "á", "o", , , vbTextCompare)

   f_ot = InStr(LCase(score1), "o") > 0

   pos = InStr(score1, "-")
   goal1 = Val(score1)
   goal2 = Val(Mid(score1, pos + 1))

   If Abs(goal1 - goal2) = 1 And f_ot Then
      If goal1 > goal2 Then
         goal1 = goal2
      Else
         goal2 = goal1
      End If
   End If

   pos = InStr(score2, "-")
   goal1p = Val(score2)
   goal2p = Val(Mid(score2, pos + 1))

   ishod = Sgn(goal1p - goal2p) = Sgn(goal1 - goal2)
   okm = Abs(goal1 - goal1p) + Abs(goal2 - goal2p)
   orm = Abs((goal1p - goal2p) - (goal1 - goal2))
   shtraf = okm + orm * 1.5

   If ishod Then
      calc01 = tableshtraf01(shtraf)
   ElseIf Not ishod And shtraf <= 2.5 Then
      calc01 = 1
   Else
      calc01 = 0
      shtraf = 0
   End If

   Select Case parm
   Case 1
      calc01 = IIf(shtraf = 0 And Not ishod, "-", shtraf)
   Case 2
      calc01 = Str(calc01) + " (" + IIf(shtraf = 0 And Not ishod, "-", Str(shtraf)) + ")"
   End Select

EndMacro:

End Function

Function tableshtraf01(shtraf As Single)
   Dim ret As Integer

   Select Case shtraf
   Case 0
      ret = 10
   Case Is <= 2.5
      ret = 8
   Case Is <= 6
      ret = 7
   Case Is <= 7.5
      ret = 6
      Case Is <= 9, 5
      ret = 5
   Case Is <= 12
      ret = 4
   Case Else
      ret = 3
   End Select

   tableshtraf01 = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Так в чем вопрос и проблема?

Comment: вопрос в том, как "изменить/исправить" функцию, чтобы она соответствовала условиям.
А проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать?

Comment: наверное плохо объяснил раз нет ответов, или размыто?

Comment: Проблема в том, что мы не будем за вас писать код. Мы можем *помочь* в написании, но полностью за вас писать не будем. У вас есть алгоритм в словесном описании. Попытайтесь перевести его в код.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, вы очень добры. Но я расписал как смог, согласно своему уровню понимания. Именно из-за него (уровня) я и обратился к добрым людям. Единственное, что могу, так это передать этот алгоритм формулой на Visual Basic. Но изменит ли это ситуацию?

Comment: Да, это немного облегчает. Потому что остается всего лишь перевести код на VB на JS. Давайте попробуем по шагам. Что вам не понятно в коде на VB?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, я могу только сказать, что мне понятно :). Это значения, которые находятся в case - их можно изменять и в зависимости от значения будет изменятся начисление очков. На VB писал не я, а человек, который и создал эту функцию. Но в JS он тоже не разбирается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я перевел предоставленную вами функцию в `js`.

Похоже, вы уже пытались менять алгоритм рассчета. Потому что алгоритм рассчета штрафа приведенный в коде на `VB` **отличается** от алгоритма приведенного в словесном описании.

Вот пример рассчета на `js`, соглассно *словесному описанию алгоритма*.

```js
function calc01(score1, score2, parm) {
  var goal1 = 0,
    goal2 = 0,
    goal1p = 0,
    goal2p = 0,
    okm = 0,
    orm = 0,
    pos = 0,
    shtraf = 0,
    f_ot = false;

  if (score1.replace(" ", "") === "" || score2.replace(" ", "") === "" || score1 === "0" || score2 === "0") {
    return "";
  }

  score1 = score1.replace(":", "-");
  score1 = score1.replace("î", "o");
  score1 = score1.replace("á", "o");

  score2 = score2.replace(":", "-");
  score2 = score2.replace("î", "o");
  score2 = score2.replace("á", "o");

  f_ot = score1.toLowerCase().indexOf("o") >= 0

  pos = score1.indexOf("-")
  goal1 = parseInt(score1);
  goal2 = parseInt(score1.slice(pos + 1));

  if (Math.abs(goal1 - goal2) === 1 && f_ot) {
    if (goal1 > goal2)
      goal1 = goal2;
    else
      goal2 = goal1;
  }

  pos = score2.indexOf("-");
  goal1p = parseInt(score2);
  goal2p = parseInt(score2.slice(pos + 1));

  var ishod = Math.sign(goal1p - goal2p) === Math.sign(goal1 - goal2);
  okm = Math.abs(goal1 - goal1p) + Math.abs(goal2 - goal2p);
  orm = Math.abs((goal1p - goal2p) - (goal1 - goal2));
  shtraf = okm + orm * 1.5;

  var res = "";
  if (ishod)
    res = tableshtraf01(shtraf);
  else if (!ishod && shtraf <= 2.5)
    res = 1;
  else {
    res = 0;
    shtraf = 0;
  }

  switch (parm) {
    case 1:
      res = (shtraf == 0 && !ishod ? "-" :
        shtraf);
      break;
    case 2:
      res = calc01 + " (" + (shtraf == 0 && !ishod ? "-" : shtraf) + ")";
      break;
  }
  return res;
}

function tableshtraf01(shtraf) {
  var ret = 0;

  if (shtraf == 0)
    ret = 9;
  else if (shtraf >= 2 && shtraf <= 2.5)
    ret = 7;
  else if (shtraf >= 4 && shtraf <= 6)
    ret = 6;
  else if (shtraf >= 6.5 && shtraf <= 9)
    ret = 5;
  else if (shtraf >= 9, 5 && shtraf <= 12)
    ret = 4;
  else if (shtraf >= 12)
    ret = 3;

  return ret;
}

function onClick() {
  res.innerText = calc01(iScore1.value, iScore2.value);
}


function runTests() {
  var tests = [
    ["3-2", "3-2", "9"],
    ["3-2", "4-3", "7"],
    ["3-3", "4-4", "7"],
    ["3-2", "4-2", "7"],
    ["3-2", "5-4", "6"],
    ["3-3", "5-5", "6"],
    ["3-2", "5-3", "6"],
    ["3-2", "5-2", "6"],
    ["3-2", "4-1", "6"],
    ["3-2", "6-5", "6"],
    ["3-3", "6-6", "6"],
    ["3-2", "6-4", "5"],
    ["3-2", "6-3", "5"],
    ["3-2", "6-2", "5"],
    ["3-2", "4-0", "5"],
    ["3-2", "7-6", "5"],
    ["3-3", "7-7", "5"],
    ["3-2", "7-5", "5"],
    ["3-2", "7-4", "5"],
    ["3-2", "7-3", "4"],
    ["3-2", "7-2", "4"],
    ["3-3", "8-8", "4"],
    ["3-2", "8-6", "4"],
    ["3-2", "8-5", "4"],
    ["3-2", "8-4", "4"],
    ["3-3", "9-9", "4"],
    ["3-2", "8-2", "3"],
    ["3-3", "10-10", "3"],
    ["3-2", "14-1", "3"],
    ["3-2", "3-3", "1"],
    ["4-4", "3-4", "1"],
    ["2-0", "1-2", "0"],
    ["3-3", "4-2", "0"]
  ];
  var resTests = tests.map(t => calc01(t[0], t[1]) == t[2]);
  var percent = (resTests.filter(f => f).length / tests.length) * 100;
  res.innerText = "percent true " + percent + "%";
}
```

```html
<label> score1
<input id="iScore1">
</label>
<br>
<label> score2
<input id="iScore2">
</label>
<br>
<button onclick="onClick()">calc</button>
<div id="res"></div>
<button onclick="runTests()">test</button>
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо. То что нужно! Да, я действительно экспериментировал и алгоритм отличается. Спасибо!

Comment: @Foliant если вам помог ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильный.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как в вашем примере кода можно осуществить изменение количества начисляемых очков? Дело в том, что формула должна быть гибкой, но при попытке изменить например количество начисляемых очков за штраф "0" результат не меняется.

Comment: @Foliant Меняйте значения в функции `tableshtraf01`, а именно в блоке `if esle`.

Comment: именно в этом блоке я пробую изменять значения 9, 7 на другие, но в результате все рассчитывается по-прежнему.

Comment: @Foliant такого не может быть. Точнее, это очень маловероятно! Если хотите, могу помочь, по скайпу Stepan.Kasyanenko

Comment: прошу прощения, все работает. У меня оказывается проблема с локальным сервером, иногда приходится по несколько раз перезагружать, чтобы в браузере отобразилась информация после изменения скрипта.